# Find radius of convergence and where holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Given$$\lim \frac{(-1)^nz^n}{n^3} $$

Applying ratio test$$|-z|\lim \frac{n^3}{(n+1)^3}\to|z| $$

so $R=1$, hence holomorphic on a unit disk?

other sources tell me that the $R=\infty$ ?

which is right?

Comment: $\;R=1\;$ is the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radius of convergence $R$ of the power series $\sum_{n=1} ^ {+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^3}z^n $ is indeed $1$.

Note that if $|z|\leqslant 1$, then $\sum_{n=1} ^ {+\infty} \left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n^3}\right|z^n $ converges because the series $\sum_{n=1} ^ {+\infty} 1/n^3$ converges. This implies that $R\geqslant 1$. 
If $|z|\gt 1$, then $\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n^3}z^n\right|$ does not converge to $0$ because for each positive $r$, 
$$\frac { (1+r)^n}{ n^3} \to +\infty .$$

Comment: is it then safe to say that it is holomorphic on a disk at origin and radius 1?

Comment: No problem for the open disk.